Adding multiple cookies for the ASP.NET Identity
I have a use case in which I need to use two /login and /logout endpoints depending on the authorization request, each will perform specific tasks.
I'm using ASP.NET Identity:
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders(); 

which configure its cookies. but I want to add a separate cookie, for the second login and logout endpoint.
adding a cookie like that:
.AddCookie("SecondScheme", options =>
             {
                 options.LoginPath = "/SecondAccount/Login";
                 options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
             });

doesn't work as expected, as the login information is still stored in the default ASP.NET Identity cookie (in addition to the new cookie).
So is there a way to define the challenge scheme of ASP.NET Identity based on the scheme defined in the Challenge method:
return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUri }, "SecondScheme");

and Signing in:
await HttpContext.SignInAsync("SecondScheme", new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));

And only use the cookie associated with that scheme, and not using the ASP.NET Identity cookie?
